# elasticsearch connection problems on windows (found.io)

Tags: python, elasticsearch, github

On my Windows I want to connect my python program to my elasticsearch cluster hosted on found.io (via heroku.)

The connection to elasticsearch times out and gives me an exception saying the "the target machine actively refused it".

```py
es = Elasticsearch(
      [elastic],
        # port=443,
        use_ssl=True,
        verify_certs=True,
        ca_certs=certifi.where(),
    )
```

I expected an indexation but received the following error message:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x03A0EC70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x03A0EC70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a PROXY issue, as in [`heroku/legacy-cli` issue 642](https://github.com/heroku/legacy-cli/issues/642#issuecomment-11281492), and documented in [using the CLI / using an HTTP proxy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#using-an-http-proxy).

Another reason is simply when the remote elasticsearch cluster is *not* started, as [in this thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused/84175).